# OpenLDAP TLS - test results in Bad file descriptor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openldap, tls

I have set up an openldap server including tls on ubuntu 14.04 following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/openldap-server.html).

While testing the connection, I get results that I can not find an explanation for.

```
ldapsearch -xLLL -Z -W -D cn=admin,cn=config -b cn=config cn=config
```

results in

```
dn: cn=config
objectClass: olcGlobal
cn: config
olcArgsFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.args
olcLogLevel: none
olcLogLevel: stats
olcPidFile: /var/run/slapd/slapd.pid
olcTLSCACertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/ldap01_slapd_cert.pem
olcTLSCertificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/private/ldap01_slapd_key.pem
olcToolThreads: 1
```

as expected. But increasing debug level

```
ldapsearch -d 2 -xLLL -Z -W -D cn=admin,cn=config -b cn=config cn=config
```

results in

```
ldap_write: want=31, written=31
  0000:  30 1d 02 01 01 77 18 80  16 31 2e 33 2e 36 2e 31   0....w...1.3.6.1  
  0010:  2e 34 2e 31 2e 31 34 36  36 2e 32 30 30 33 37      .4.1.1466.20037   
ldap_read: want=8, got=8
  0000:  30 0c 02 01 01 78 07 0a                            0....x..          
....
Enter LDAP Password: 
....
  00a0:  a6 c4 2f 78 97 fb e1 ea  ce c3 03 d6 8c 0e fa 75   ../x...........u  
  00b0:  df e7 89 91 e8 df e2 70  94 ca d3 c7 5c af a0 d0   .......p....\...  
  00c0:  bf 76 10 70 47                                     .v.pG             
tls_write: want=117 error=Bad file descriptor
```

So, what makes me skeptical is the message *error=Bad file descriptor*.

My */etc/ldap/ldap.conf* is

```
uri ldap://myfqdn/
ldap_version 3
ssl start_tls
tls_cacert /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem 
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

In */var/log/syslog* I see for the last test

```
Jan  8 17:03:00 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=0 EXT oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.20037
Jan  8 17:03:00 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=0 STARTTLS
Jan  8 17:03:00 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=0 RESULT oid= err=0 text=
Jan  8 17:03:00 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 fd=19 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:39973 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Jan  8 17:03:00 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 fd=19 TLS established tls_ssf=128 ssf=128
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=1 BIND dn="cn=admin,cn=config" method=128
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=1 BIND dn="cn=admin,cn=config" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=1 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=2 SRCH base="cn=config" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(cn=config)"
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 op=3 UNBIND
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: conn=1008 fd=19 closed
Jan  8 17:03:04 kyrill slapd[29857]: connection_read(19): no connection!
```

Actually, I have no idea how to track this down. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.